# Spring RestTemplate not loading the correct custom ObjectMapper in the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, jackson, resttemplate

In my servlet.xml, I have the following RestTemplate configuration:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" >
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                        <property name="objectMapper" ref="jodaObjectMapper"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jodaObjectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jodaObjectMapper" class="com.xyz.JodaObjectMapper"/>
```

When I deploy the app, the converter is setting up my custom mapper through the setObjectMapper method correctly. But when I use the restTemplate in my service, it is using the default ObjectMapper.

```
ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, String.class);
```

[image: debug]

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance